# Oracle SQL: Find a leading or trailing spaces in all columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following dataset where I want to find the column that has either a leading space or trailing space. How do I write the query where it shows me the exact value that has the space?

`data`:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT '1' id, 'Jim' fname, 'Jam' lname     FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '2' id, 'Jon' fname, 'Doe ' lname    FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '3' id, 'Sam' fname, 'Lee' lname     FROM dual
)

SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE fname LIKE ' %' OR fname LIKE '% ' OR lname LIKE ' %' OR lname LIKE '% ';
```

The above query gives the following output, which is not helpful in knowing the column that has the value.

`output`:

```
| ID | FNAME | LNAME |
|----|-------|-------|
| 2  | Jon   | Doe   |
```

I want a query that gives me the following output instead:

```
| ID | FIELD_NAME | ISSUE_DESCRIPTION | FIELD_VALUES |
|----|------------|-------------------|--------------|
| 2  | LNAME      | Trailing Space    | Doe          |
```

**P.S.: In the actual table, I need to perform this check on 35+ columns.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpivot and then filter using `SUBSTR` (or `LIKE`) and use a `CASE` expression to generate the issue description:

```sql
WITH data AS (
    SELECT '1' id, 'Jim' fname, 'Jam' lname     FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '2' id, 'Jon' fname, 'Doe ' lname    FROM dual UNION
    SELECT '3' id, 'Sam' fname, 'Lee' lname     FROM dual
)
SELECT id,
       column_name,
       CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(value, 1, 1) = ' ' AND SUBSTR(value, -1, 1) = ' '
       THEN 'Leading and trailing space'
       WHEN SUBSTR(value, 1, 1) = ' '
       THEN 'Leading space'
       WHEN SUBSTR(value, -1, 1) = ' '
       THEN 'Trailing space'
       END AS issue_description,
       value
FROM   data
UNPIVOT (
  value FOR column_name IN (fname, lname)
)
WHERE   SUBSTR(value, 1, 1) = ' '
OR      SUBSTR(value, -1, 1) = ' ';
```

Which outputs:

| ID | COLUMN_NAME | ISSUE_DESCRIPTION | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | LNAME | Trailing space | Doe |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h_utT2z7)